# Legal values of quantum field can take? $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{H}$, ..?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, second-quantization, classical-field-theory, spin-statistics

> Main issue: What are the legal and possible values of the quantum field can take?

Clarify by examples:

(1) For example, for the spin-0 Klein Gordon field $\phi$,
we may choose it to be:

- real $\mathbb{R}$.
- complex $\mathbb{C}$.

(2) For the spin-1/2 fermion field $\psi$,
we may choose it to be a spinor which needs to be

- Grassman variable

but can also be

- complex $\mathbb{C}$. (**Dirac or Weyl spinor/fermion**)
- We can ask: Can it be in real $\mathbb{R}$? (**Majorana or Majorana-Weyl spinor/fermion**)

(3) For the spin-1/ boson field $A_\mu$,
we may choose it to be a vector which needs to be

- real $\mathbb{R}$ usually for photon field.
- but can it be complex $\mathbb{C}$?

(3) How about the spin-3/2 fermion field $\psi_\mu$?

- can it be in real $\mathbb{R}$, complex $\mathbb{C}$, quaternion $\mathbb{H}$, ..?

Comment: In some theories the field takes values in a Lie group.

Comment: Not sure why this is put on hold. It's a pretty good question. It boils down to, at least, as far as I can think, studying the stability of a theory resulting from such generalizations. 'Stability' here could mean unitarity, absence of negative energy states, etc. One example I know of a similar generalization is when you make the worldsheet coordinates in string theory non-Archimedean, p-adic valued, giving you p-adic string theory (e.g. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321388902076)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I was thinking of the fields in nonlinear sigma models, not gauge fields. These models were not part of my QFT course, so I may completely misunderstand them. I thought the fields in these models have values in Lie groups such as $O(3)$. Is that not the case?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform The Scholarpedia article “Nonlinear sigma model” (http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Nonlinear_Sigma_model) says that the fields map spacetime into a Riemann target manifold $M$. It then goes on to say, “All the isometries of the target space $M$ form the group $G$ representing the global symmetry of $M$. The most important case is given by the target space that is a Lie group $G$ itself.” So this seems to confirm my statement. Do you agree?

Comment: I re-ask a different and focused one here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/482858/

Comment: @all, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/482858/42982 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/482860/42982

Comment: An answer would depend on which model that we're talking about. And there are a lot of models to choose from...

Comment: @G.Smith Ah, yes, you're absolutely right. I thought you were referring to gauge fields, thus my comment. But non-linear sigma models do take values in a generic homogeneous manifold, which may indeed be a Lie group. Although strictly speaking, the fields can be thought of as coordinates on the manifold, and so $\mathbb R$-valued. But anyway.