# Legal values of spin-1/2 field can take: $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{H}$, .. (Grassmann)?

Tags: fermions, dirac-equation, spinors, complex-numbers, clifford-algebra

For the spin-1/2 fermion field $\psi$,
we may choose it to be a spinor which needs to be

- Grassmann variable

but can also be

- complex $\mathbb{C}$ Grassmann. (**Dirac or Weyl spinor/fermion**)
- We can ask: Can  be in real $\mathbb{R}$ Grassmann. (**Majorana or Majorana-Weyl spinor/fermion**)

What are the legal values of spin-1 field can take? real $\mathbb{R}$, complex $\mathbb{C}$, quaternion $\mathbb{H}$,  .. (Grassmann)? (p.s. I remember S Adler tries to construct quaternion QFT -- is this related to the quaternion field.)

Comment: In how many spacetime dimensions and in what signature? Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53318/2451

Comment: when I say complex and real - I mean complex Grassmann or real Grassmann -- I say this in separate order -- let me fix it

Answer (score 1):

Fermion field can NOT be complex $\mathbb{C}$ or real $\mathbb{R}$. That is a common mistake in some text books. Fermion field must be real/complex/quaternion Grassmann variable.

Case in Point: the Majorana mass term would not be possible, if not for the Grassmann nature of the Fermion field.

In addition to real $\mathbb{R}$/complex $\mathbb{C}$/quaternion $\mathbb{H}$ Grassmann variable, you may go further up the division algebra ladder and toy with the idea of non-associative octonions $\mathbb{O}$ [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.09182)

If that wets you appetite, you might want to check out sedenions $\mathbb{S}$ [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.03186).

Mind that one should be talking about octonion/sedenion **Grassmann** variables, the authors of the above linked papers failed to do so.